# jQuery wrap element around a lot of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html and want to wrap with javascript or jquery a div around all li's (its not definied how many li's there are)

```
<div class='example1'>
  <div class='example2'>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div class='example3'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  ...
  <li></li>
  <li></li> 
</div>
```

The Result should look like

```
<div class='example1'>
  <div class='example2'>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div class='example3'>
  <div class='lis'>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </div>    
</div>
```

I'm not able to add anything else the existing html :(

Can you please help me?

Comment: This is not even valid markup !

Comment: sorry, i want to keep it as simple as possible
in real I would add two divs and one ul

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) :

```
$('li').wrapAll('<div class=lis></div>');
```

But the HTML norm specifies that [`LI` elements are only permitted in `UL`, `OL` and `MENU`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html), not `DIV`.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gm6zx/)

Comment: thank you :) I didn't find the wrapAll Method. This works really fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
(function($) {
$.fn.customWrap = function(wrapper) {
    if (!this.length) return this;
    var wrap = $(wrapper),
        sel = this.selector || this.get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase();
    return this.each(function() {
        var more = $(this).next(sel).length;
        console.log(this,more);
        $(this).replaceWith(wrap).appendTo(wrap);
        if (!more) wrap = $(wrapper);
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

And Invoke like:

```
$(function() {
$('li').customWrap('<div class="lis"></div>');
});
```

Or you can use [jQuery wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) but this will wrap all `li`  in the page.. not the consecutive ones..

See difference [here (with wrapAll)](http://jsfiddle.net/BpBZj/1/) and [here (custom function)](http://jsfiddle.net/BpBZj/2/)

Comment: ... Why not use the existing function ?

Comment: I've seen your edit. But usually the selector isn't just 'li' but a specific enough one...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [$.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap the set of matching elements inside another element

Comment: No : this wraps them separately. See my answer.